# Send enums values with a message

Tags: java, eclipse

```
public enum Number {
    one(), two(), three(), four();
}
```

I want to send a message with the numbers separated by a comma:
The numbers are one, two, three and four

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to use the method `name()` in your `enum`

```
System.out.println(Number.one.name() + ", "  
  + Number.two.name() + ", "
  + Number.three.name() + ", "
  + Number.four.name());
```

Or, if you want to populate your `enum` in a `List` first, because your numbers are many, you could populate them using `EnumSet.allOf` like this:

```
List<Number> numberList =
             new ArrayList<Number>(EnumSet.allOf(Number.class));
```

And then simply use it like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberList.size(); i++){
   System.out.print(numberList.get(i).name() + (i == numberList.size() - 1 ? "" : ","));
}
```

*(A little syntatical sugar to distinguish between the last number and the rests are added)*

Comment: but if i have a lot of numbers?

Comment: @Nerio then, you may want to first populate them in an array or list... there, I updated my answer

Comment: @Nerio great! ;) in that case please do not forget to accept my answer (tick V in the top left of my answer), This way, the community will know that this question already have an accepted answer. besides, both the acceptor and the answerer will get some reputation. you could also upvote the questions/answers which you find useful in the stack overflow since you already have enough reputation to do that.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you read the java documentation here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: While, this link may answer the question, it is highly recommended to brief a bit about the link as well, so that even if it is deleted, the answer doesn't becomes false.

Comment: this document don't help me a lot